# Where is Shell Path in mac. .bash_profile Dont works correctly

Tags: macos, terminal

When i use:
nano .bash_profile

the terminal show me:

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/opt/x11/bin:$PATH


# Setting PATH for Python 3.4
# The orginal version is saved in .bash_profile.pysave
PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib"
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin"
#XAMPP
#export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/bin:$PATH"
#export PATH="/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/lib:$PATH"
```

But when i open a new terminal only shows.  echo $PATH prints.

```
/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
```

The problem is that when i execute a command the terminal  returns :

```
command not found
```

I need to execute this command for the terminal to operate properly

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/opt/x11/bin:$PATH
```

and  echo $PATH prints.

```
/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/opt/x11/bin:/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin
```

What can i do to open and edit the correct shell PATH ?

Answer (score 0):

You are overiding your PATH variable every time you export. your .bash_profile should be

```
export PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/opt/x11/bin
export PATH="/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.4/bin:${PATH}"
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/lib:$PATH"
export PATH="/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin:$PATH"
```

this way your current path is added to the end of the new path variable

Comment: it try with your example but only works in the current  terminal, when i open another one, the changes dont are't saved.

Comment: i execute export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/sbin", and it works after close all terminals. .